# Outlook 2013 Can't move email to folder becasue email has changed

Tags: windows-8, email, microsoft-outlook-2013

Frequently when trying to move a message from my inbox to an outlook folder, I get the error message that it cannot move the email because the email has changed. I have only begun getting this message for a few weeks; never had the problem previously. Sometimes it will let me get away with moving a copy of the email to the folder, but sometimes not.  Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem. I've opened the email with double click and pressed ctrl-save confirm the dialog. Now I have twice the same email, but I can move them both

Answer (score 1):

If you have replied to the email you're trying to move the problem is probably due to the copy in drafts not matching the copy you're trying to move. 
There's more info [Here](http://roger.dilsner.com/outlook-2013-operation-performed-message-changed-solution/)

Answer (score 0):

No solution, but a way round it: right-click the mail in the IN-box and select 'delete'. From the trash folder it can be filed without problems.